# What happens to a medium when it is impacted by a projectile whose velocity is higher than the respective medium’s speed of sound

Tags: projectile

From my understanding, the speed of sound in a medium is the rate at which energy can be conferred from one constituant particle to another (whether this be an atom, or molecule). So if a projectile were to impact a medium at a velocity exceeding said medium’s speed of sound it appears, according to my likely flawed definition, that the constituant parts of that medium wouldn’t be able to transfer the energy from the projectile to surrounding particles fast enough to allow the projectile to continue moving through the medium. Can someone help explain to me what happens in this instance? Helping me better understand how energy operates at the microscopic level additionally would also be much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure what kind of magic you're expecting. An object traveling faster than the speed of sound will create a shot wave, or a sonic boom. The medium will resist the object slowing it down if there isn't some other means of propulsion.

Comment: It doesn’t mean the particles can’t be pushed faster than the medium’s speed of sound by the projectile, just that the disturbance does not propagate ahead of the projectile as it normally would at subsonic speeds.

Comment: A [shock wave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) is produced.

Answer (score 1):

the projectile will continue moving through the medium, it will pass through it's own sound waves. The only resistance is the normal friction of passing through the medium. Picture a high powered rifle firing a bullet through air at sea level, the bullet will be travelling much faster than sound waves, it will silently hit a target some distance ahead, a few moments later the sound of the gun firing will reach the target.

Comment: Doesn't drag spike at arounf the speed of sound? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#/media/File:Qualitive_variation_of_cd_with_mach_number.png